# How to solve "Controller 'IDE Controller' does not support hotpluggin"?

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

I install virtualbox from apt-get.

When I want to set shared folders, it shows Controller 'IDE Controller' does not support hotpluggin".

How to solve it?

Thank you~

Comment: Have you tried using a "SATA Controller"? You can change it somewhere in the machine settings

Comment: 'Enable USB 2.0 controller' under **USB** in Settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you~ @maythux 's answer is right.

I try to remove virtualbox-ose and install virtualbox on website( 2 files).

Then enable all the USB settings.

It works!

Thank you~